# How to ignore a .go file in a module?

Tags: go, go-build

I am rewriting in Go a home-grade program of mine that was previously in Python, learning on the way. As I reconsider whole sections of the code, it would be great if I could ignore some `.go` files I wrote (they throw compilation errors which is OK as they are not synchronized with my latest approach to the problem).

I could move them out of the directory, or rename them but I was wondering whether there would be a more idiomatic way to ignore some `.go` files in a module directory?

Comment: Here is the relevant documentation: https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Build_constraints

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Build tags fit perfectly to your use case.

A Build Constraint or also known as Build Tag is used to include or exclude files in a package during a build process. With this, we can build different types of builds from the same source code.

So if you want to exclude a file from the build process, give it a different Build Tag. For example if you use `//go:build exclude` at the top of the file when you perform `go build` it won't be included. Note that `exclude` can be any word.

For more details on the Build Tags check out the following article by Dave Cheney [here](https://dave.cheney.net/2013/10/12/how-to-use-conditional-compilation-with-the-go-build-tool)

### TLDR

> Add
>
> `//go:build exclude` for go v1.17 and above
>
> `//+build exclude` for go v1.17 and below

to the top of the file you wish to ignore.

Comment: From go 1.17, you should use `//go:build exclude`.